# Dimension of of the subspace formed by all matrices which commute with a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a matirx. Consider the subspace 
$$C(A)=\{X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})\text{ }|\text{ }AX=XA\}$$

How to prove that the dimension of $C(A)$ is at least $n$?

The only idea I could get was that the dimension is at least $d$ where $d$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial, $f(A)$ commutes with $A$.

Comment: Possibly helpful, though I haven't come up with a solution yet, is that all the matrices in $C(A)$ are simultaneously triangulable. Thus WLOG, they are all upper triangular.

Answer (score 4):

Use Jordan canonical form.  A Jordan block $J = \lambda I + N$ of size $m$ commutes with the $m$ matrices $N^j$ for $j=0\ldots m-1$.